# Can't open Market application after updating my Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-tab

Just updated firmware for my Samsung Galaxy Tablet.

Now I can't enter Market application. When I click the Market application icon, I get this message "Application not installed". And update was completed successfully with Kies.

Comment: Have same state, market is not installed on device after update software via air. Any idea?

Comment: Which version did the update give? (`Settings` -> `About device` -> `Android version` and `Build number`)

Comment: Build number: HTJ85B P7510XWKL1 Android version: 3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to access the Market from a home screen shortcut or from the app drawer? Updates can sometimes break shortcuts so try to open it from the app drawer. Another thing you can try is to reset market data from `Settings` -> `Applications` -> `Manage applications` -> `All` -> `Market` -> `Clear data` and `Clear cache`.